# How to find element by color in selenium using python

Tags: css, selenium

This is my case.Two div case are the almost the same, but I need click only "Claim" from first one.Can I use background color to indentify my element? Or any other ideas?

1.

```
<div class="well well-sm" style="width:150px;margin:5px;text-align:center;float:left;">
  <p><b style="color:#227A11">$0.005</b></p>
  <p><a href="./seecashlinks.php?ocd=open&amp;id=96396" class="btn btn-success" style="background:#0373F1;">Claim</a></p>
</div>
```

2.

```
<div class="well well-sm" style="width:150px;margin:5px;text-align:center;float:left;">
  <p><b style="color:#227A11">$0.001</b></p>
  <p><a href="./seecashlinks.php?ocd=open&amp;id=22952" class="btn btn-success" style="background:#CC07DD;">Claim</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question clearly and let us know what you have tried so that we can help you out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can identify the div-element that contains an anchor element with the background color you were searching for using xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@style='background:#0373F1;']/ancestor::div[1]"));
```

* If there are several anchor-elements with that background color on your site you would have to modify your xpath accordingly (you would need to first search for all "possible" parent elements

In your case you could for example first search for all div elements that contain class "well":

```
"//div[contains(@class, 'well')]/a[@style='background:#0373F1;']/ancestor::div[1]"
```